# Datatables date range filter not working on EJS Project

Tags: javascript, html, web, datatables, ejs

I'm trying to make my table sortable using this library https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables.html, but when i enter the date on the input field the table not showing any result

```
<body id="page-top">
    <!-- Page Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper w-100">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <%- include ('../views/components/sidebar')%>

            <!-- Content Wrapper -->
            <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">

                <!-- Main Content -->
                <div id="content w-100">
                    <!-- Begin Page Content -->
                    <div class="container-fluid">

                        <!-- Page Heading -->
                        <h1 class="h3 mb-2 text-gray-800">Pending Request</h1>

                        <!-- DataTales Example -->
                        <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Minimum date:</td>
                                                <td><input type="date" id="min" name="min"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Maximum date:</td>
                                                <td><input type="date" id="max" name="max"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <table class="table table-bordered w-100" id="example" width="100%"
                                        cellspacing="0">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>NIK</th>
                                                <th>Company</th>
                                                <th>Location</th>
                                                <th>Departement</th>
                                                <th>Created</th>
                                                <th>Updated</th>
                                                <th>Action</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>NIK</th>
                                                <th>Company</th>
                                                <th>Location</th>
                                                <th>Departement</th>
                                                <th>Created</th>
                                                <th>Updated</th>
                                                <th>Action</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tfoot>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                                                <td>System Architect</td>
                                                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                                <td>61</td>
                                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                                <td> <a href="/panel/panel_detail_update"><button
                                                            class="btn btn-info">Detail</button></a>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td> Nixon</td>
                                                <td>System Architect</td>
                                                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                                <td>61</td>
                                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                                <td> <a href="/panel/panel_detail_update"><button
                                                            class="btn btn-info">Detail</button></a>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Tiger </td>
                                                <td>System Architect</td>
                                                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                                                <td>61</td>
                                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                                                <td> <a href="/panel/panel_detail_update"><button
                                                            class="btn btn-info">Detail</button></a>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container-fluid -->

                </div>
                <!-- End of Main Content -->

                <!-- Footer -->
                <%- include ('../views/components/footer')%>

                    <!-- End of Footer -->

            </div>
            <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
    <%- include ('../views/components/button_scroll_to_top')%>

        <!-- Logout Modal-->
        <%- include ('../views/components/logout_modal')%>

            <!-- Add new Admin Modal-->
            <%- include ('../views/components/add_new_admin_modal')%>
                </div>

                <!-- Core Javascript-->
                <%- include('components/javascript'); %>
```

this is my javascript script file where i import everything

```
<!--    File Jquery -->
<script src="/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugins/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

<script src="/jquery/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Plugin for the momentJs  -->
<script src="/js/plugins/moment.min.js"></script>
<!--    File Bootstrap -->
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
<script src="/js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>
<!--    Plugin for Select, full documentation here: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select -->
<script src="/js/plugins/bootstrap-selectpicker.js"></script>
<!--  Plugin for the DateTimePicker, full documentation here: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ -->
<script src="/js/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<!--  DataTables.net Plugin, full documentation here: https://datatables.net/  -->
<script src="/js/plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugins/dataTables.dateTime.min.js"></script>
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I already tried to copy the exact code from the documentation

Comment: (1) The code in your question is missing several pieces which are provided in the official example. Does the code in your question reflect _exactly_ what you are using in your code? (2) In the official example, where it provides a list of additional "JavaScript library files" - have you added all of them to your code? For example, have you included the `moment.js` file?

Comment: @andrewjames sir i already added the script where i import the external files, i already check all those missing files, and i dont see any error in my console, can you please help me check it

Comment: Sorry - I missed the inclusion of `moment.js`. But I still do not see all of the code from the sample - in fact, I see less now than before your edit. I am not familiar with EJS - so maybe that handles things differently from how I expect.

Answer (score 0):

So I came across this issue with this plugin and on the DataTables forums I was advised to write my own custom plugin https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search, which in retrospect is way better than the date range plugin.

I am not 100% sure what exactly you are looking for as it wasn't described too well, but what this function does is filter through dates for the current week, it will only show DataTable items where the Monday - Friday dates are in line with those of the current week. If this isn't quite what you're looking for, please provide a more in depth explanation and I can alter the code if need.

```
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter ) {
        var now = moment();
        var monday = now.clone().weekday(1);
        var friday = now.clone().weekday(5);
        
        let mondayF = monday.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
        let fridayF = friday.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
        
        //console.log(sundayF); 
        //console.log(fridayF);
        
        var sMonday = searchData[2];
        var sFriday = searchData[10];
        
        if (mondayF == sMonday && fridayF == sFriday) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```